# Splitting rules in mvpart vs rpart

Tags: r, rpart, cart-analysis

I would like to make classification trees to predict the presence/absence of 1 bird species based on several variables. I know that rpart handles univariate partitioning and mvpart handles multivariate partitioning, but I'd like to use mvpart for my one-variable tree because of its more flexible output. Does anyone know of a reason that I should not do this? Will the splits be different in rpart vs mvpart with the same exact input?

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be guaranteed that the splits will be the same; `mvpart()` is minimising the within groups sums of squares whereas `rpart` for a classification tree will be minimising the Gini coefficient (by default IIRC).

You may end up with the same model/splits but as the two functions are using two different measures of node impurity this may just be a fluke.

FYI, `mvpart` is fitting a regression model but you want a classification model.

Finally, consider using the **party** package and its function `ctree`; it has much nicer outputs than `rpart` by default but is, again, doing something slightly different in terms of model fitting.

As an aside, also look into the **plotmo** package which includes enhanced plots for a number of tree-like models including, IIRC, `rpart` ones.